# modified files in destination are not updated ant

Tags: ant

I have two folders : src and dst. I am using sync  in order to have dst as an updated copy of  src .

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <project name="Hello World Project" default="info">

 <target name="info">

 <sync todir="dest">
  <fileset src="src" />
 </sync>

 </target>
```

It work perfectly , with one exception. If I modify the content of a file from destination folder , it will not be updated . Why is that and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync` is supposed to ensure `dest` contains everything from your sources and is up-to-date.  If it contains files even newer that inside your sources then those will be retained.

If this is not what you want but you rather prefer to replace changes made in `dest` you need to set the task's `overwrite` attribute to `true`.

Comment: Thank you. This copies all the files from source folder to destination folder no matter what . What I would like was only to check what files are different , and then make the changes in destination folder.

Comment: For this you'd use `uptodate` using your `dest` as `sourcefiles` and your `src` as part of your `mapper` and it would signal modified files in `dest` by returning `false` inside `condition`.